# Which Shaiva sampradayas do twelve Jyotirlinga adhere to?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, jyotirlinga

The Jyotirlingas are twelve of most holiest tirthas for Shaivas. They are -

> Somnath in Gir Somnath, Gujarat
>
> Mallikarjuna in Srisailam, Andhra Pradesh
>
> Mahakaleswar in Ujjain, Madhya Pradesh
>
> Omkareshwar in Khandwa, Madhya Pradesh
>
> Kedarnath in  Rudraprayag,  Uttarakhand
>
> Bhimashankar in Maharashtra
>
> Vishwanath in Varanasi, Uttar Pradesh
>
> Trimbakeshwar in Nashik, Maharashtra
>
> Vaidyanath in Deoghar, Jharkhand
>
> Nageshvara in Dwarka, Gujarat
>
> Ramanathaswamy in Rameshwaram, Tamil Nadu
>
> Grishneshwar in Aurangabad, Maharashtra

So my question is,which Sampradaya do these twelve Jyotirlingas belong to.Which Agamas do they follow in their daily rituals(like Vaishnavas follow their Agamas like different Panchratras etc).